# User Profiles using properties in Java

Tags: java, properties, profile

I am making a math game in Java and I want to create the ability for the user to create a local account (or log in to an existing one), which would have a unique properties file. How would I do this?

Comment: I didnt understand the question - do you ask how to create a unique ? this can be based on unique user id like email address
or you ask how to create properties file in java?

Comment: This is a VERY broad question. As far as I can understand, you would like to create a user account locally on users' computers? Depending on how much information you'll be saving, you could either save the information in a plain-text file or you could use some other means, such as XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options to look into. Java comes with the necessary libraries with which you can create, open, read and write to files. Using the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class, you could create an account file, for instance "User1.properties", and save the information in an easy to parse format. If you're looking to go one further, you can look into using XML or JSON, which are commonly used formats for saving information in this way. Here's some helpful links to get you started.

[Using files in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

[Using XML in Java](http://java.sun.com/xml/tutorial_intro.html)

[Using JSON in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-json-tutorials/)

Another option you have available is to use a database in a similar fashion to websites. The type of database you use is up to you, although MySQL is an example of one commonly used database. [Once again, here is a link to help you get started with MySQL in Java](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/).

Regardless of what you use, you will need to take the username and password provided (or whatever combination of login credentials you would like your system to use), and compare them with those stored in your file or database.